# iPhone 6+ simulator loads @2x image instead of @3x image

Tags: ios, uiimage, iphone-6-plus

I have @1x, @2x, and @3x images in an asset catalog and verified their resolutions are correct. But when running 6+ simulator and printing the UIImage in debugger, it shows the @2x image dimensions and the @2x image is shown in the simulator screen. Any idea what causes this or how to fix it?

Comment: You probably aren't using a launch screen file and you don't have an iPhone 6+ launch image. You need one or the other. Without them your app is being run as a scaled iPhone 5 app.

Comment: Double-checked but App target Launch Image Src is set to LaunchImage, and in LaunchImage the RetinaHD 5.5 has a 1242x2208 img. Not sure what else to look for.

Comment: You don't need both. If you have the launch screen, you don't need the launch image.

Comment: Launch Screen File is not set, only LaunchImage is and it has a 1242x2208 image for Retina HD 5.5. I've tried on device and simulator and it's loading 2x version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause and posting here if it might help others. The @3x img was 3x the size for iPhone 5, rather than iPhone 6+. Eg. its width was 960 instead of 1242 and the 6+ loaded the @2x img instead. After scaling up to 1242, the @3x img loads.

Answer (score 0):

In your target general settings, provide a lunch screen storyboard file for the lunch sceen file option.

Comment: Double-checked but App target Launch Image Src is set to LaunchImage, and in LaunchImage the RetinaHD 5.5 has a 1242x2208 img.

Comment: What you need to do is create a lunchscreen storyboard and add it to you lunch screen file.